# Optimal on-disk data structure for searching a file?

Tags: java, data-structures, b-tree, binary-search-tree

I've spent a couple of hours reading posts that were related to the question in a bid to try and come up with a solution, but I wasn't really successful in coming up with one.

So here goes: I was once asked in an interview which data structure I would use to search a if a particular word existed in a file. The file is also supposedly big enough to not be able to fit in the memory and the interviewer was really looking for an on-disk solution.

Is the B-Tree an on-disk data structure?

A Binary Search Tree is an in-memory data structure isn't it?

Comment: I took your question(s) to be "Is B-tree on disk?". "Is binary tree on-disk?". Seems like you write something but actually mean something else :-) Amazingly, people who read this question seem to have understood what you really want!

Comment: I'm sorry if I confused you - what I was trying to do was to build up a context and then ask the questions. I was actually looking to find out if there are any data structures that I've not heard of, and also to find out if my answers (given to the interviewer) were correct. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really two different possible questions here:

1. Given a massive file, and a word, how do you check if the word exists in the file?
2. Given a massive file, how do you build an index so that you can efficiently check if an arbitrary word exists in the file?

The first problem is efficiently solved with Boyer-Moore and a linear search through the file. If you're only searching once, building an index is a complete waste of time.

Regarding the second problem, it sounds like the interviewer is really pushing B-Trees.

Comment: that's probably it, that's what I told him too :)

Answer (score 2):

Both are just data-structures and can be both on-disk or in-memory. It depends on how you choose to use them.

btw, B-Trees were motivated by a need to have on-disk structures. Binary search trees are just a special case of B-trees, in one way.

Comment: @Moron (lol!) - How do you specify if the data structure is to be used on-disk or in-memory? (I'm sorry if that's a very naive question!)

Comment: @user: It is not like it is a config parameter! You have to consider what it would take to store the data-structure on the disk. For instance, in a binary search tree (or even a Btree), a pointer to another node could be translated to an offset you seek within a file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, any DS can be used anywhere, it is about being efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a data structure that maps one node to one page of disk space. This will minimize disk activity.

Because a B-Tree is often used for this. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree, specifically the section "Time to search a sorted file".

Comment: So a B-Tree is the best data structure for this purpose? (Just confirming)